# Flink DDL can not parse 2 different json roots from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, pyflink

I am sending message from Kafka to Flink in Python. I have 2 different json roots in one Kafka topic. My json roots with examples:

1- {'Message1': {'b': 'c'}}

2- {'Message2': {'e': 'f'}}

Flink can consume these messages but can not parse for DDL format.

```
        CREATE TABLE audienceInput (
      `messageKey` VARBINARY,
        `message` VARBINARY,
        `topic` VARCHAR
        ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'kafka',
        'topic' = 'mytopic',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '****:9092',
        'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
        'value.format' = 'json'
        )
        """
```

How can I parse two root types of messages in Flink DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly declare the two `Message1` and `Message2` fields in the table schema.

```sql
CREATE TABLE audience_input (
  Message1 ROW(b STRING, c STRING),
  Message2 ROW(e STRING, f STRING),
  ...
) WITH
  ...
  'value.format' = 'json'
)
```

They will then appear as columns with nested fields in the resulting column.

See the [Json format doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/formats/json/) for more details about the json-format.

Comment: Thank you! Just need an adjustment in ROW. It should be as below: ROW( `b` STRING,
`c` STRING)

Comment: Oh indeed, I had mixed up the syntax there, I updated my answer based on your input

Comment: b, c, e and f should have back-tick symbols but I could not add it here

Comment: I don't think back-ticks are systematically required, most of the time I don't use any quotes and it works fine while keeping the expression well readable. Such quotes are only necessary when the column name contains special characters like space  or `-` or so.